# Multiline output in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, multiline

I'm working on a program, with a GUI, that will need to output multiple lines to some kind of TextArea. I tried doing this with a `JTextArea`, but it turns out that when setting a new text to JTextArea, the old text gets deleted. Is it some kind of way to print multiple lines to a `JTextArea`? Or should I use an entirely different method/component for displaying text?

I hope this will clarify:

```
    for (int n = 0; n <= this.length; n++) {
        for (int m = 0; m <= that.length; m++) {
            txtaResult.setText("thisthis is " + n + "\n");

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(9)+1;
            txtaResult.setText(thatthat, " + m + ", is " + randomNumber\n");
        }
    }
```

(`txtaResult` is a `JTextArea`) So I want the text in the two `txtaResult.setText` to stay put in the `JTextArea` and add onto each other during all iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) method instead of `setText`. Everything's behaving exactly as I'd expect it to - I would have been really surprised if `setText` *had* appended.

If you don't want to use `append` for some reason, you can call `getText` and concatenate the text yourself:

```
txtaResult.setText(textaResult.getText() + "whatever");
```

... but using `append` is cleaner and may be more efficient.

As an aside, your loop bounds look odd (usually you'd use `<` rather than `<=`) and it would be better to create a *single* instance of `Random` and call `nextInt` on it multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and for the other tips! This solved my problem!